# Dismiss modal view controller with a custom segue

Tags: objective-c, uistoryboardsegue

I have created two custom segue files and in both, I have overrode the `perform` method. However, it seems that the custom segue only works when presenting the new `UIViewController`, and the reverse one, does not animate just dismisses the source `UIViewController`.

Reverse custom segue:

```
- (void)perform {
UIViewController *sourceViewController = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *sourceTabBarController = sourceViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController;
    UIViewController *destinationViewController = self.destinationViewController;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(destinationViewController.view.bounds.size);
        [destinationViewController.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *destinationViewControllerImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *destinationViewControllerImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:destinationViewControllerImage];
    destinationViewControllerImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    destinationViewControllerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGRectGetWidth(destinationViewController.view.frame), CGRectGetHeight(destinationViewController.view.frame));

[destinationViewController.view insertSubview:destinationViewControllerImageView atIndex:1];

// Add animations
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4f
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         destinationViewControllerImageView.center = CGPointMake(-CGRectGetWidth(destinationViewControllerImageView.frame) / 2, -(CGRectGetHeight(destinationViewControllerImageView.frame) / 2));
                     }
                     completion:nil];

    [sourceViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segues add a new version of a view controller. When I was starting out I had some *interesting* problems with using segues to dismiss view controllers.

Instead of writing a custom segue, you should use a custom animation block in the view controller you are "dismissing to".

Comment: OK, I feared that may be the case! How would you go about doing it? Would you add the dismissal code in an IBAction then the uiview animation code block in the viewwilldisappear? Becuase that's what I tired and the animation doesn't run just gets dismissed. By the way, I removed the reversal segues from the storyboard.

Comment: What you should do is have the `IBAction` call a method in the view controller to be dismissed. In the completion block of your animation, dismiss the controller (so the animation finishes before the controller is dismissed).

Comment: Ok, so I have an `IBAction` which houses `[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         //my animation
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                     }];` however, the animation does not take place, then view controller is just dismissed straight away. Have I misunderstood your comment?

Comment: As you can see by the times in my Log... `2012-08-14 17:16:00.740 myApp[2070:c07] animations block`
`2012-08-14 17:16:00.742 myApp[2070:c07] completion block`

Comment: That looks right. What happens if you remove the call to dismiss the view controller?

Comment: Then the problem is your animations.

Comment: this is my animations block `destinationViewControllerImageView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(destinationViewControllerImageView.frame) / 2, -1000.0f);` (the -1000 is so it explicitly moves for now).

Comment: I think the problem is with my `destinationViewControllerImageView`. Thanks for all your help, I will get it sorted and report back! :)

Comment: Feel free to post another question if you have problems with a different topic; it's easier to answer questions when they are focused on one thing. Also you'll get more attention for your question ;)

Comment: Will do! When I use the 'forward' segue I create and add subviews onto the destination view controller. I gave these views a unique tag, which I then use to reference them in my animation block, animating their properties. Everything seems great so far! Thanks :)